# How to import regulator to simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I've made a regulator in Matlab's rltool and I could import it in to Workspace, but I need to get it in to Simulink, so I can connect it with my system. Is there any way, how to get a regulator from Workspace or from rltool to Simulink as a siso block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When exported to the MATLAB Workspace, your controller should be an LTI Object.

Open the Simulink Library Browser, find the Control Toolbox library, and drag the [LTI System](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ltisystem.html) block into your model.  Then insert the name of your Workspace variable into the block.